# ! Missing } inserted. <inserted text> } l.212 \end{figure}

Tags: input, gnuplot

i work with gnuplot and latex and i had the following problem

```
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text>
}
l.212 \end{figure}
```

this is my code

```
\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\input{essai} // there are two files essai : essai.eps and essai.tex created with gnuplot
\end{figure}
```

when i remove `\init`, there is no error but when i added it i had the error.

Thanks

Comment: It's obvious, your error lies within `essai.tex`. Done.

Comment: Just a heads up `//` is not used for comments in LaTeX, we use `%`

Comment: It would help to see the gnuplot script that generated the obviously wrong `essai.tex`